Remove Exec Command After Execution Or Run in Local Thread
I've created a function in python to execute generic script via exec(). It works perfectly but it creates functions globally. I need to create them locally and run them then I need to remove them.
My example script:
def demo_handler(request):
    ...
    return None

My executor function is:
def execute(body: ExecutorCommand):
    try:
        exec(body.script, globals())
        result = demo_handler(body.request)
        return {"success": True, "data": result}
    except Exception as ex:
        return {"success": False, "error": {"type": type(ex).__name__, "message": repr(ex)}}

When I send a first-request with script, it works like expected. Then even if I don't send a script, I can reach previous executed functions. But I don't want it. Is there a way to remove previous executed-functions?

Don't pass globals() to exec() if you don't want to pollute the global namespace.

Pass an empty dict instead of globals. This will resolve your problem

@Olivier if I remove globals(), I couldn't reach script function demo_handler. Is there a way to reach it without globals?

If you pass a dict to exec(), then demo_handler should be stored in that dict.

thanks, global_vars = {}  exec(handler_script, global_vars) global_vars[fun]() this works.

Solved like:
def execute(body: Command):
    fun_name = _generate_unique_function_name()
    try:
        handler_script = body.handler_script.replace("demo_handler", fun_name)
        exec(handler_script, globals())

        ...
        result = globals()[fun_name](**params)
        return {"success": True, "data": result}
    except Exception as ex:
        logging.error("Unexpected exception on execute command: %s", repr(ex))
        return {"success": False, "error": {"type": type(ex).__name__, "message": repr(ex)}}
    finally:
        if fun_name in globals():
            del globals()[fun_name]
        else:
            return {"success": False, "error": {"type": "Unknown Function", "message": "Couldn't found demo_handler function in script"}}


def _generate_unique_function_name():
    return "handler_" + str(uuid.uuid4()).replace("-", "_")


Or Alternative solution (Thanks to @Olivier and @Muslimbek Abduganiev):
def execute(body: Command):
    fun_name = "demo_handler"
    try:
        global_vars = {}
        exec(body.handler_script, global_vars)

        ...
        result = global_vars[fun_name](**params)
        return {"success": True, "data": result}
    except Exception as ex:
        logging.error("Unexpected exception on execute command: %s", repr(ex))
        return {"success": False, "error": {"type": type(ex).__name__, "message": repr(ex)}}

